# How to get the total number of inputs in a ipython session?

Tags: python, ipython

For example in a session like the following:

```
In [1]: x = 1

In [2]: y = 2

In [3]: z = 3
```

How can I programmatically find out that there are so far 3 inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `_ih` ipython internal variable and call it using `globals()`:

```
In [1]: x = 1

In [2]: y = 2

In [3]: z = 3

In [4]: len(globals()['_ih'])
Out[4]: 5

In [5]: print(globals()['_ih'])
['', 'x = 1', 'y = 2', 'z = 3', "len(globals()['_ih'])", "print(globals()['_ih'])"]
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `globals()` here; `len(_ih)` works.

Answer (score 0):

> All output results are automatically stored in a global dictionary
>   named Out and variables named _1, _2, etc. alias them. For example,
>   the result of input line 4 is available either as Out[4] or as _4.
>   Additionally, three variables named _, __ and ___ are always kept
>   updated with the for the last three results. This allows you to recall
>   any previous result and further use it for new calculations

May be you can look at global dict and check last key value with format `_number`.

*Source: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/interactive/tutorial.html*